# Blazor Server app cannot connect to AWS DynamoDB database - returns error that the requested resource cannot be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, blazor

I'm pretty new to web app development but am doing a project where I'm trying to visualise data in a web app. The data is being stored in an AWS DynamoDB database, and I'm having trouble connecting the two. I finally got the code compiling but now it just opens an error page saying "Requested resource not found" instead of my app.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgkkv.png)

The AWS documentation says there should be an error code, error name, and error description, but I seem to be just getting the name.

It doesn't matter which page of the web app I try to set as the home page, the error message appears immediately, so it seems to me to be a result of the initial set up and not the actual BatchGetItems call.

I'm fairly sure my account (and access keys) should have permission to access the table I need. Although I'm confident that my credentials are correct, but I may be implementing them wrong.

This is what my implementation looks like in the program.cs file, having initialised the access key, secret key, and region in the appsettings.json file:

```
// Retrieve AWS credentials from appsettings.json
var awsOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AWS");
var accessKeyId = awsOptions["AccessKeyId"];
var secretAccessKey = awsOptions["SecretAccessKey"];
var region = awsOptions["Region"];// Create the DynamoDB client
var config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig
{
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region)
};
var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, config);
```

Any ideas how to begin debugging this?

Comment: Don't share error codes as images.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Do you mind if I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are resolving your region correctly
2. Try a DynamoDB ListTables API call to see if you can list the tables in your region
3. Be sure you specify the table name correctly, casing included.

Let me know if all of those options fail.